# MySQL order query by priority field and status field

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time using `ORDER BY` on one of my tables. One of my log tables contains a **priority** field with values of either `high`, `medium`, or `low`; a **status** field which is either `open` or `close`. How do I query the records so the status of `open` come before those which are already set to `close` then in both `open` and `close` the values are arranged by priority in the ff order `high` then `medium` then `low`. Is this possible using a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
order by find_in_set(`priority`, 'open,close'),
         find_in_set(`status`, 'high,medium,low')
```